# Warning: include(includes\jconfig.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, wamp

I am struggling with this issue for more than two days now. I have an installation of wamp server on my pc in C:\wamp folder. My document root is C:\wamp\www.

I am trying to include two php files from a subfolder into another code file in the current folder using include statements. The weirdest thing is it includes one file but not the other.

The codes files are placed as below.

```
C:\wamp\www\jsonrpcclient\add.php
C:\wamp\www\jsonrpcclient\includes\jsonrpc.php
C:\wamp\www\jsonrpcclient\includes\jconfig.php
```

The add.php file has two include statements as below:

```
include( "includes\jsonrpc.php" );
include( "includes\jconfig.php" );
```

When I executed add.php in the browser, I get the following error.

```
( ! ) Warning: include(includes\jconfig.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\jsonrpcclient\add.php on line 4
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  138656  {main}( )   ..\add.php:0

( ! ) Warning: include(): Failed opening 'includes\jconfig.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\jsonrpcclient\add.php on line 4
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  138656  {main}( )   ..\add.php:0
```

I have tried several solutions as mentioned in other posts, but none worked.

The STRANGEST issue is out of two includes the jsonrpc.php include works but not the second one (jconfig.php)!!! Why? Both are in the same sub folder within the current folder where `add.php` is.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure this will solve your problem, but shouldn't you be using forward slashes in your include statements rather than backslashes?

Comment: I had forward slashes initially. As part of the debugging effort, I have tried the backslashes. Neither of them works. Also, like I mentioned, one file gets included with no issues with the same formatting!

Comment: Things i would try: 1) comment out the first include or check it isn't changing the default directory. 2) i never use relative paths for includes. i.e.  _`include __DIR__  ."/includes/jconfig.php";`_  note: this filename format works fine on windows. 3) rename the file to another name and create a brand new file, without copying, in case there are 'odd' characters in the filename.

Comment: Yes!, it worked with the creation of a brand new file and copying the contents of jclient.php into it. Looks like the old file had some corruption. I didn't have to make any changes to the path. Thanks,

Comment: On a side note, it's generally a bad idea to use \ in paths in programming languages outside of literal strings (using `'` in PHP) as they are treated as escape characters.  Edit: Heck, I even had a hard time getting MarkDown to display a lone \ in a code line... I had to not put it in backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!, it worked with the creation of a brand new file and copying the contents of jclient.php into it. Looks like the old file had some corruption. By the way, I just put back the forward slashes in the include paths (I had changed them to black slashes as part of debugging). They still stay relative to the current folder as posted and it works. Thanks to @Ryan Vincent's reminder about the good old problem of file corruption.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use blow code**

```
include( "includes/jsonrpc.php" );
include( "includes/jconfig.php" );
```

**OR**

```
include(__DIR__.'/includes/jsonrpc.php');
include(__DIR__.'/includes/jconfig.php');
```

**By replacing your code**

```
include( "includes\jsonrpc.php" );
include( "includes\jconfig.php" );
```